# how to set the multiple marker on google map android?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have done with google map marker with multiple location and i have add some hospital location with field like hospital name,longitude and latitude,that i retrieve from firebase and load to searchable spinner which has hospital name. when i click on hospital name its as to mark to that particular location but in my code all the location are marked but when i click it going to that marker and coming back to current location what can do to show the location when i click the hospital name in searchable spinner any one please help me out

Thanks in advance

```
This is my java code

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, IFirebaseLoaddone, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double longitude, latitude;
    private SearchableSpinner searchableSpinner;

    DatabaseReference hospitalRef;
    IFirebaseLoaddone iFirebaseLoaddone;
    List<Hospital> hospitals;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        searchableSpinner = findViewById(R.id.searchviewid);
        BubbleSeekBar bubbleSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //init Db
        hospitalRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("hospital");
        //init interface
        iFirebaseLoaddone = this;

        hospitalRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                List<Hospital> hospital = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot hospitalsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    hospital.add(hospitalsnapshot.getValue(Hospital.class));
                }
                iFirebaseLoaddone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(hospital);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                iFirebaseLoaddone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });

        searchableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                hospitalRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        setMarker(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        setMarker(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        bubbleSeekBar.setOnProgressChangedListener(new BubbleSeekBar.OnProgressChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int progress, float progressFloat) {
                //textView.setText( String.format( "on change %d",progress ) );
            }

            @Override
            public void getProgressOnActionUp(int progress, float progressFloat) {

            }

            @Override
            public void getProgressOnFinally(int progress, float progressFloat) {

            }
        });

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longtitude", 0);

        findViewById(R.id.zoomin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.zoomout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager
                .PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate Zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
                mMap.clear();

                MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
                mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                mp.title("Source");

                mMap.addMarker(mp);
                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                mMap.animateCamera(Zoom);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Hospital> hospitalList) {

        hospitals = hospitalList;
        //get all data
        List<String> name_list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> latitude = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> longitude = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Hospital hospital : hospitalList)
            name_list.add(hospital.getName());




        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name_list);
        searchableSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_location:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new LocationFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_setting:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SettingFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
               logout();
                break;

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void logout()
    {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private  void  setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());

        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

        if(!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
            mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location)));
        }
        else
        {
            mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);

        }
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for(Marker marker : mMarkers.values()){
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(),100));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i See your code, the problem is with the setOnMyLocationChangeListener because you are animating map to your current locationevery time your gps gives you update.

Remove these two lines:

```
mMap.moveCamera(center);
mMap.animateCamera(Zoom);
```

it will look like this after :

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate Zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
                mMap.clear();

                MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
                mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                mp.title("Source");

                mMap.addMarker(mp);'

            }
        });
    }
```

hope it will solve the problem

Comment: nothing works even though its works same when i click hospital name it is going and coming back to current location

Comment: if i move the map automatically it coming to current location